# $o_p(1)$ property of sample median estimator

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, parameter-estimation, median

$\textbf{Motivation:}$ Van der Vaart - Asymptotic statistics [Example 5.11]

$\textbf{Setup:}$ Suppose I have $i.i.d$ random variables $X_1,...,X_n$. Define the sample median $\hat\theta_n(\omega)$ as the median value of $\{X_1(\omega),...,X_n(\omega)\}$ for every $\omega \in \Omega$. Define the estimator $\theta \mapsto \Psi_n(\theta) \equiv \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nsign(X_i-\theta)$.

$\textbf{Question:}$ How do I show that $\Psi_n(\hat\theta_n) = o_p(1)?$

I know we can first write $\Psi_n(\hat\theta_n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (1\{ X_i - \hat\theta_n >0 \} - 1\{X_i - \hat\theta_n<0 \} ) $, but it seems that writing out $\hat\theta_n$ mathematically is challenging.

Answer (score 1):

If $\hat \theta_n$ is a sample median, then at least $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ of the $X_i$ are on each side of $\hat\theta_n$. So (as you have in your question):

$$|\Psi_n(\hat \theta_n)| = \frac{1}{n}\left|\sum_{i=1}^n 1\{ X_i  > \hat\theta_n \} - 1\{X_i < \hat\theta_n \} \right| \leq 
\frac{1}{n} 
$$

Since the quantity inside the absolute value is $0$ when $n$ is even and there are no ties, and cannot be larger than $1$ since otherwise $\hat\theta_n$ is not a sample median.

Comment: To apply Lemma 5.10, we need to ensure $\Psi_n(\hat\theta_n) = o_p(1)$. I am not sure why $\Psi_n(\hat\theta_n) \overset{p}{\rightarrow} \Psi(\theta_0)$ in your statement

Comment: @dante I updated my answer

Comment: I have 2 questions. Firstly, $\widehat\theta_n$ may not be the minimum of $\Psi_n$, because the definition of a median estimator does not mean it minimizes $\Psi_n$. In fact, $\Psi_n$ is minimized at $\theta=max\{ X_1,…,X_n\}$, which is not the median estimator. Second of all, it seems to me that your argument depends on $\Psi_n(\widehat\theta_n) \geq 0$, which may not be true

Comment: Good point, I wrote it as if $\Psi_n$ was a M-estimator, but it is in fact a Z-estimator.

Comment: I think this proof works. However, it might require a condition, mainly that the random variable is $X_1$ has continuous distribution. This is because the $X_i$ are iid, so this implies all the random variable has continuous distribution. Therefore we can safely say that for any $i\neq j$, we have $\mathbb{P} (X_i=X_j)=0$. In this case, there exists a set $B$ such that $\mathbb{P}(B)=0$, and for any $\omega \in B^c$, $|\sum_{i=1}^n sign(X_i - \widehat\theta_n) |(\omega) = 0$ or 1, depending on whether $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: Assuming continuity is sufficient you're right. I also think there's a problem with my proof since it's possible to have several ties such that the upper bound I gave is wrong. Let me rework this part of the proof.

Comment: your proof is correct. When $n$ is even, you get$ \frac{-1}{n}$ and when $n$ is odd you get $0$, assuming each $X_i$ is distinct. This is true on an almost sure set, if we assume continuity of the distribution

Comment: @dante you might want to check the discussion at the end of page 43

Comment: thanks! I see it!